# Running console program in PHP

Tags: php, webserver

I wrote a simple PHP code to execute a console program:

```
<?php
$cmd = escapeshellcmd('progName.exe arg1 arg2 arg3');
exec($cmd);
?>
```

If I run the command on the console directly on the server, it works. However, when I run the PHP on the browser, it doesn't work. The process `progName.exe` is running (checked using Task Manager on the server), but it never finishes. This program is supposed to compute some parameters from the arguments and write the result to a binary file, and also produce a .WAV file. Here is the error message I get on the browser:

```
Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout

Detailed Error Information
      Module    FastCgiModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
     Handler    PHP
  Error Code    0x80070102
```

Then I wrote a simple console program that write a sentence to a text file (`writeTxt.exe hello.txt`). Using the same PHP script, I ran it on the browser and it works.

I already tried to increase the timeout on the server, but still have the same error.
What could cause this problem?

Comment: What happens if you run `writeTxt.exe hello.txt` (and not `progName.exe `) via PHP from the console?

Comment: How to run it via PHP on the console?

Comment: Looks like problem with the return, it just executes progName and does not return, what does progName looks like?

Comment: Is the console application one you've developed? Have you tried attaching a debugger?

Comment: @Wiggler Jtag: However, if I run `progName.exe` directly on the console (on the server), it works. `progName.exe` reads from 3 arguments and produces 2 files: a binary file and a .WAV file.

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: yes, I developed the console program. Is it possible to debug a console program run via PHP?

Comment: Depending on the toolchain you used to develop the console app, most support attaching to a running process, pausing it to find out where it is in code. Worst case scenario would be to use something like [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) which allows you to monitor the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a program in PHP using the `exec` function (e.g. `exec('dir')`), PHP waits until it is ended *or* you sent it to the background and PHP comes back directly ([see documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php), especially the comments).

According to your posted PHP sources (`$cmd = escapeshellcmd('progName.exe arg1 arg2 arg3');`) the program is not sent to background by PHP - so what stays is that `progName.exe`...

1. ...sends itself or a fork to the background (unlikely, but look into the sources of `progName.exe`)
2. ...is waiting for input (<-- this is my favorite)
3. I missed something ;-)

As I said I bet it is the second option. Hope that helped a bit.